# How to immediately resize the minibuffer window?

Tags: window, minibuffer

Suppose that I have this function, that inserts some stuff into the minibuffer:

```cl
(defun foobar ()
  (interactive)
  (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
      (lambda ()
        (let ((resize-mini-windows t))
          (save-excursion
            (insert "foo\nbar")
            (fit-window-to-buffer))))
    (read-from-minibuffer "string: ")))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-RET") 'foobar)
```

It works fine if I call it from any buffer, except when I'm already in the minibuffer.

For example, if I eval `(read-from-minibuffer "test: ")`, and then press <kbd>M-RET</kbd>, my minibuffer becomes `string: foo` (note the 1 line height). After I press any character, I see that `bar` is also in the minibuffer.  The problem is that the minibuffer height won't update until I press any character.

Why does this happen and how to get around it?

Comment: Your example in the question behaves fine (I can see both `foo` and `bar`). But I know that issue you are talking about and I have seen that frequently with `ido`, since last 2 or so weeks. But the issue doesn't repeat after the first few times you enter something in the minibuffer to increase its height. I am looking forward to the cause for this. I am using emacs built from master branch in git.

Comment: What version of emacs are you using?  I'm using 24.4.1 (from Debian unstable) and it works OK for me.  When I go `M-x foobar`, I see `string: foo`[newline]`bar`.

Comment: I tried 24.5 and 25.

Comment: You're right, it's a regression. It still works fine on 24.3.1, but is broken on 24.5

Comment: It sounds like the consensus is that this is bug in 24.5. Someone please report it (`M-x report-emacs-bug`). And then post that as an answer (and OP please then accept that answer).

Comment: Any news on this? Did the bug get reported? Fixed?

Comment: @Drew Yes, it works fine on 27.2.

Comment: Excellent. Please update your question with that info. And preferably provide a link to the bug report for anyone interested. (It's somewhere [here](https://debbugs.gnu.org/).) Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions and answers need to stand on their own, to be helpful (e.g. searchable). Thx.